# Cannot connect to SQL Server Reporting Services Configuration Manager

Tags: ssrs-2008

[image]Hi all,

I have a SQL server 2008 with Reporting service installed. I can connect to the server through its url (http://192.168.1.120:8080/ReportServer/  and http://192.168.1.120:8080/Reports)
and I can manage the server and upload reports. However I cannot open the reporting service configuration manager.

Any Ideas??

Comment: The problem was solved by simply restart the server :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply I restarted the server and everything is ok now :)